# Gerar arquivo JSON Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou precisando gerar um arquivo JSON com Delphi 7. Utilizo a biblioteca LKJSON.

Até consegui gerar o arquivo, porém não ficou do jeito que precisaria.

Abaixo código que usei para gerar o JSON:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  js: TlkJSONobject;
  s: string;
  i : Integer;

begin

  SQLConnection1.Open;
  taUF.Open;

  js := TlkJSONobject.Create;

  try

    js.Add('estado', TlkJSONobject.Create);

    taUF.First;
    while not taUF.Eof do begin

      with TlkJSONobject(TlkJSONobject(js['estado'])) do begin
        Add('sigla', taUF.FieldByName('UFSigla').AsString);
        Add('nome', taUF.FieldByName('UFNome').AsString);
      end;

      taUF.Next;

    end;//while

    i := 0;
    s := GenerateReadableText(js, i);
    Clipboard.SetTextBuf(PChar(s));

  finally
    js.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Este é o resultado obtido:

```
{
  "estado":{
    "sigla":"RJ",
    "nome":"RIO DE JANEIRO",
    "sigla":"SC",
    "nome":"SANTA CATARINA"
  }
}
```

Estou precisando que ficasse desta forma:

```
{
  "estado":
    {
    "sigla":"RJ",
    "nome":"RIO DE JANEIRO"
    },
    {"sigla":"SC",
    "nome":"SANTA CATARINA"
    }
}
```

Comment: A estrutura do *JSON* que você quer retornar, será que ela é válida? teste aqui: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Essa forma que você quer gerar está incorreta.
Não analisei o seu código ainda, mas pela estrutura que você está tentando montar,acredito que você precise trabalhar com Listas.

Comment: Dica: Dentro de ` with TlkJSONobject` você deve adicionar um novo objeto como `js.Add('sigla_estado_aqui', TlkJSONobject.Create);`. Após isso, adicione a sigla e nome a este objeto criado no laço.

Comment: Conforme o @VictorTadashi falou, a estrutura Json que vc quer usar está incorreta. Não tem como uma chave ("estado") ter mais de um valor a não ser que este valor seja um array json.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como citado nos comentários, voce vai ter que trabalhar com listas para gerar o JSON, segue um código como exemplo:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  JsonFull: TlkJSONobject;
  PropertyJson: TlkJSONobject;
  JsonList: TlkJSONlist;
  s: string;
  i: Integer;

begin
  JsonFull := TlkJSONobject.Create;
  JsonList := TlkJSONlist.Create;

  try
    for i := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      PropertyJson := TlkJSONobject.Create;
      PropertyJson.Add('sigla', 'UF' + IntToStr(i));
      PropertyJson.Add('nome', 'Estado' + IntToStr(i));
      JsonList.Add(PropertyJson);

    end;

    JsonFull.Add('estado', JsonList);

    i := 0;
    s := GenerateReadableText(JsonFull, i);
    Clipboard.SetTextBuf(PChar(s));

  finally
    FreeAndNil(JsonFull);
  end;

end;
```

Foram criado 3 Variáveis novas:

**JsonFull: TlkJSONobject** - Que representa o JSON com a lista dos objetos

**PropertyJson: TlkJSONobject** - Que representa cada Estado

**JsonList: TlkJSONlist** - Que representa a lista com os estados

Com isso cada objeto vai pertencer ao outro, como uma cascata:

```
PropertyJson.Add(Estado) > JsonList.Add(PropertyJson) > JsonFull.Add(JsonList)
```